# Strip whitespace from string

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm trying to learn assembly (Intel x86 with NASM on Linux) and unsurprisingly I'm having some trouble.

The following is meant to take a buffer of text, remove all spaces and put the result in another buffer. It's part of a larger project I'm doing as a way to learn, and I'm developing each part individually first. In the actual project the message is going to come from a file, here I'm just using a hardcoded string (`Msg`) for testing purposes.

But it's not working. I've been fiddling with it for a while now, but I'm sure I've missed some fundamental concept somewhere or something.

```
[SECTION .data]
Msg   db '    %d Whitespace, thanks      ', 10, 0

[SECTION .bss]
BUFFSIZE   equ 80 
BufferA    resb BUFFSIZE
BufferB    resb BUFFSIZE

[SECTION .text]
extern printf

global main

; PROCEDURE stripwhite
; INPUT     None
; OUTPUT    None
; NOTES     Strips all leading and trailing whitespace from BufferA
;           Result is stored in BufferB
stripwhite:
    pushad                  ; Save caller's registers

    mov eax, BufferA        ; Source string
    mov ebx, BufferB        ; Output string
    .loop:
        mov cl, byte [eax]  ; Get a single character from the source
        cmp cl, 0
        je .end             ; End if character is null
        cmp cl, 32
        jne .save           ; Save it if it's not a space
        add eax, 1          ; Otherwhise skip to next character
        jmp .loop
    .save:
        mov byte [ebx], cl  ; Save character in output buffer
        add eax, 1          ; Move on to next character
        add ebx, 1
        jmp .loop
    .end:
        mov byte [ebx], 0   ; Add a null at the end

    popad                   ; Restore caller's registers
    ret

main:
    push ebp                ; Set up stack frame for debugger
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx                ; Must preserve ebp, ebx, esi and edi
    push esi
    push edi
    ; start

    mov dword [BufferA], Msg
    call stripwhite

    push 0
    push BufferB            ; Push message string
    call printf             ; Print line count
    add esp, 8              ; Clean up the stack

    ; end
    pop edi                 ; Restore saved registers
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp            ; Destroy stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

I'm kinda wondering why it seems I have to use `dword` in the line before `call stripwhite` above when both `Msg` and the two buffers use bytes, but the linker (called by GCC in this case) throws an error when I use anything else:

```
stripwhite.o:stripwhite.asm:82: relocation truncated to fit: R_386_8 against `.data'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Maybe that has something to do with it, but I can't figure out what.

The following seems to work just fine, and it's basically identical except the code is not inside a procedure.

```
[SECTION .data]
Msg   db '    %d Whitespace, thanks      ', 10, 0

[SECTION .bss]
BUFFSIZE   equ 80 
BufferA    resb BUFFSIZE
BufferB    resb BUFFSIZE

[SECTION .text]
extern printf

global main

main:
    push ebp                ; Set up stack frame for debugger
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx                ; Must preserve ebp, ebx, esi and edi
    push esi
    push edi
    ; start

    mov eax, Msg
    mov ebx, BufferB
    .loop:
        mov cl, byte [eax]
        cmp cl, 0
        je .end
        cmp cl, 32
        jne .save
        add eax, 1
        jmp .loop
    .save:
        mov byte [ebx], cl
        add eax, 1
        add ebx, 1
        jmp .loop
    .end:
        mov byte [ebx], 0

    push 0
    push BufferB            ; Push message string
    call printf             ; Print line count
    add esp, 8              ; Clean up the stack

    ; end
    pop edi                 ; Restore saved registers
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp            ; Destroy stack frame
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[SECTION .bss]
BUFFSIZE   equ 80 
BufferA    resb BUFFSIZE
BufferB    resb BUFFSIZE
```

`BufferA` is an array.

```
mov dword [BufferA], Msg
```

This is putting the address of `Msg` in the first 4 bytes of `BufferA`, probably not what you want. You could call `memcpy` instead.

Comment: Ah! I knew there was something suspect about that line :) Thanks, that seemed to do the trick. I'm assuming there's no simpler way to do it in assembly rather than going through the C library?

Comment: @MCXXIII: you can do a `rep movs`, or write your own loop.

Comment: Thanks. Writing my own loop sounds less simple, but I may look into `rep movs`